# How is the result of this python program calculated?

Tags: python

could anybody please help explain how the results of the python program in the following picture are calculated? especially the 45.. I maybe too dumb to comprehend but please help me.

[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq4LK.jpg)

I really appreciate the help, thank you very much!

Comment: Hint. It is 1+2+...+9 =45

Comment: X is 10. Hence, the second look will not get executed.

Comment: Try assigning *x=1* after *product=1* to fix the issue with your product calculation. The output of 45 is as expected because that's the sum of the numbers from 1 to 9 inclusive

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @user2512443, its just a summation of numbers upto 10. In order to understand how the output is calculated, you just have to understand and dry run it with the input. Go step by step, and try to figure out what is happening in your code. For example: In your code:

```
x=1
sum=0
while x<10:
     sum = sum + x
     x = x+1
```

If you go sequentially, x=1 and sum=0. Then you go to the loop which says that until x is less than 10, do these statements. So what will happen is:

```
1) 1st iteration:
   sum = sum+x -> sum = 0+1 =1
   x = x+1 -> x = 1+1 = 2

2) 2nd Iteration:
   sum = sum+x -> sum = 1+2 = 3 (Here, we take new value of sum)
   x = x+1 -> x = 2+1 = 3
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the first block of code sums all the numbers from 1 to 9.

Process:

```py
#to start with, a number variable is assigned to x, and to sum
x=1 #This holds our counter
sum=0 #this holds the result
#Then, a loop is run through while x is less than 10.
while x<10:
    sum+=x #the variable x is added to sum
    x+=1 #x is incremented
```

Then, the next block of code assigns a variable **Tries a loop** and then outputs the two variables `sum` and `product`;

```py
#Assign product to be 1
product=1

##NOTE: this loop will not happen because x is already above or equal to ten
while x<10:
    #If this loop was valid, this would multiply all numbers from 1-9
    product= product*x
    #If this loop was valid, increment x
    x+=1
```

The loop will not happen because `x=10`, which means that unless you reassign `x` to be `0`, the while loop won't happen, and `product` will always equal `1`.
Finally:

```py
#output both values of sum and product
print(sum, product)
```

If this was your own code, try this instead for more correct output.

```py
#to start with, a number variable is assigned to x, and to sum
x=1 #This holds our counter
sum=0 #this holds the result
#Then, a loop is run through while x is less than 10.
while x<10:
    #show working
    print(sum,"+",x,"=",sum+x)
    sum+=x #the variable x is added to sum
    x+=1 #x is incremented
#Assign product to be 1
product=1
#NOTE: x is reassigned for a working while loop next time
x=1
#loop while x is less than 10
while x<10:
    print(product,"×",x,"=",product*x)
    #multiply product by x
    product= product*x
    #increment x
    x+=1
#output both values of sum and product
print(sum, product)
```

Ta-da

Comment: You are a heroic teacher, thank you very much!